# Returning Entity Framework class from Web API throws "failed to serialize the response body for content type" exception

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm facing the following problem, I have an Object Model BlogEntry:

```
public class BlogEntry
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime BlogEntryDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BlogEntryTitle { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BlogEntrySummary { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BlogEntryContent { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BlogEntryPublishedBy { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool BlogEntryPublished { get; set; }
        public int BlogCategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual BlogCategory BlogCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

I generated the controller with the model and I have the method:

```
 // GET: api/BlogEntries
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IQueryable<BlogEntry> GetBlogEntries()
        {
            return db.BlogEntries;
        }
```

The problem is that when I test the method I have error in the serialization:

> the 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'

I tried to fixed using the following code in the WebAPIConfig.cs:

```
 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter
                        .SerializerSettings
                        .ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

And actually this solve the problem locally, but when I publish the app to Azure keep giving me the error code 500.
Note: I debug the method and I don't have a problem in the code, is very simple actually.

Any idea please

### Exception in the Browser

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.BlogEntry_2BC5105C1EBC22432CBA0E820087939FDB4E152CC4026BA3BC6DDDD9C1156A4D' with data contract name 'BlogEntry_2BC5105C1EBC22432CBA0E820087939FDB4E152CC4026BA3BC6DDDD9C1156A4D:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at WriteArrayOfBlogEntryToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract ) at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

Comment: Could you upload the exception message you get in Azure?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to get the exception, but I'm calling the method with javascript and I'm getting error code 500, and when I execute the url I got `{"Message":"An error has occurred."}`

Comment: @Win I updated the question with the response that I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is it is trying to serialize **BlogCategory** too.

```
public virtual BlogCategory BlogCategory { get; set; }
```

First of all, it is not a good practice to return **Entity** classes from Web API *(or any API for that matter)*. Normally, we map **Entity** into **DTO** (Data Transfer Object).

The easiest way to test is to create a DTO class -

```
public class BlogEntryModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime BlogEntryDate { get; set; }
    public string BlogEntryTitle { get; set; }
    public string BlogEntrySummary { get; set; }
    public string BlogEntryContent { get; set; }
    public string BlogEntryPublishedBy { get; set; }
    public bool BlogEntryPublished { get; set; }
    public int BlogCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Then return it instead of BlogEntry.

```
return db.BlogEntries
    .Select(x => new BlogEntryModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        ...
    })
    .ToList();
```

*Proper way is to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) and Repository Pattern, but it is out of the scope of original question and I do not want to sidetrack from OP.*

Comment: Thanks @Win, but If I remove the `public virtual BlogCategory BlogCategory { get; set; }` When I generate the database Entity framework will understand that those tables are related?

Comment: You do not want to remove it; it will break relationship between tables.

Comment: Sorry then what is the solution?

Comment: Well, at least you can test above the code to make sure it solves the main problem. After that, you can decide how you can improve the code. ***FYI**: returning Entity classes are definitely not a good practice for any API development.*